# Set same width two tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tables that show data from database.

Now I set 1st table for headlines and 2nd table for the data.

I set like this

```
<table class="t_status">
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</table>
```

In table #2

```
<table class="t_status">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>California</td>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Greg</td>
    <td>LA</td>
```

Now facing the problem when data display, table 1 and table 2 set different width.

This is the CSS

```
table
{
empty-cells: show;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

.t_status
{
border-collapse: collapse;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;
width: 100%;    
margin-top: -1px;
}

.t_status td, th
{
border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 40pt;
font-weight: bold;
}

.t_status td
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}

.t_status th
{
font-size: 40pt;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use two tables? Use `th` for headings

Comment: @Morpheus Or at its best - `thead`

Comment: I use 2 tables cause, after that will use marquee, so when data in marquee, table head will fixed stay in top

Comment: So you can insert `<tr><td colspan="3">yourmarquee<td></tr>` later after heading. Or maybe I don't understand something? http://jsfiddle.net/eV7M5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put them like this:

```
<table class="t_status">
<tr>
   <td>No</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Address</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and

```
<table class="t_status">
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Michael</td>
   <td>California</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Greg</td>
  <td>LA</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if am correct you are using two tables for scrolling effect of head and data, so you will get table header for all the data.

to achieve this effect you can try using jquery table jtable
[sample code](http://ruturaj.net/automatic-header-stick-to-scroll-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Your html syntax is incorrect. Use tr tags:-

```
<table class="t_status">
<tr>
   <td>No</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Address</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put all information into one table, thus you can assure that the rows have the same width.

```
<table class="t_status">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>California</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Greg</td>
            <td>LA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have forgot the `<tr>` tags. By the way, if you want to preserve your markup (correct or not, but two different tables), you can try with [nth selectors](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child) and give a fixed width to each cell:

```
.t_status td:nth-child(1) {
    width:2em;
}
.t_status td:nth-child(2) {
    width:5em;
}
.t_status td:nth-child(3) {
    width:5em;
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8sVQ/2/).